# Python - implementing numpy.corrcoef

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vector, correlation

I have two vectors and want to find the correlation between them. 
Method #1: I can use Python `numpy.corrcoef(a, b)` based on [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html). 
I was wondering how I can implement it. 
Method #2: I tried to implement it using dot function as explained [here](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/prof/waves/rnd/paper_html/node22.html). However, the values are not the same. 
Example: 
`a = [1,4,6]` 
`b = [1,2,3]`

Method #1: 
`np.corrcoef(a, b)[0][1]` 
The result is: 0.99339927

Method #2: 
`np.dot(a, b) / math.sqrt(np.dot(a, a) * np.dot(b, b))` 
The result is: 0.9912011825893757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.corrcoef` returns the Pearson correlation coefficient according to [the manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).

So we should normalize each vector first by subtracting the sample mean:

```
a = np.array([1,4,6])
b = np.array([1,2,3])
a = a - np.mean(a)
b = b - np.mean(b)
np.dot(a, b) / math.sqrt(np.dot(a, a) * np.dot(b, b))
```

which yields `0.9933992677987827`.